# Php use $_SESSION for storing my vars

Tags: php

Is it a good practise, to use the php session object, to store several of my variables, can be arrays of request results.

I need this method, because I would like to do the request in a php file, store the result and immediately, (depending on result) redirect to a page,
It's probably not the best way, that's why I'm asking

thx for any advice,

edit: structure:

```
index.html
handler.php
view1.php
```

in index.html, I've got a

```
<form action="handler.php" ...
```

in handler.php, I construct a request and get a result,

```
if ($result->success) 
    header("location ./view1.php");
else 
    echo 'failed';
```

in view1.php, I would like to list the result array

Comment: can you provide a code example with some context into your question?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing what you want to do; this is something pretty basic and a normal thing to do (as stated in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webshops do it - so why shouldn't you?

Some of the larger eCommerce frameworks store complicated data and objects in sessions and PHP handles this pretty well.

Comment: right, but big vars stored in sessions, would increase much the browser mem

Comment: No. The point of sessions is to store the data serverside. Only cookies store data clientside (and cookies have a size limitation about 4k or so). Using serverside sessions allows you to store basically anything of any size without being dependent of client limitations.

Comment: I'm not really sure the "webshops do it" argument has anything to do with when and how to use this technique. @ca11111 is probably better served with explanation in what cases it's reasonable and when it is not (i'd advice against using it as some a place to store every variable for you code, so they're all nice and global. I've seen people do this, but there are good practices that involve sessions)

Comment: @Nanne It might not be a great argument, but eCommerce solutions is a great reference for applications storing complex data structures in sessions. And the question was not on the technique, but whether or not it is good practice.

Comment: I was trying to say that it is good practice in _some_ cases with some purpose. If you are saving your database username and password in the session so you can easily reach it from all files... well, you get the idea I hope :). I agree about the reference btw, but there is very little information about what @ca11111 is going to save in the session, so some additional warnings might be valid. The fact that webshops use sessions doesn't mean that all uses of sessions are valid :)

Comment: @Nanne I get the idea, yes :) Storing data should be with some sense and logic ofc.

Comment: @all yes was wondering If storing various heterogeous data in $_SESSION was being clumsy, but I don'y have choice, since with redirections, other Objects would be lost by my *.php

Comment: Sessions? Rest? Where is this going?

Answer (score 1):

That's what sessions are for! So the general answer is "Yes: it's a good practice".

Here are some alternatives, however:

1. Consider using ajax calls to update parts of the loaded page without reloading it;
2. Cookies - not good for big amount of data, but generally can live longer than a session. Not useful in your particular case, however;
3. SQL servers are usually well-optimized, and when your query returns lots of rows and you cut those into sections with a `LIMIT` clause, or just repeat exactly the same request soon after the first time, the subsequent requests aren't of such a big load for the database server.

I just seen your update to the question.
AJAX can do the trick for you the best. I can imagine it all done within a single web page:

1. form data is submitted by an AJAX call to you `handler.php`, which..
2. returns either a JSON-packed array of results or a short string `NOT FOUND`, for example.
3. Then, the JS on your page either creates a new DOM element - a table, or a set of div's, with the returned results, or just creates a new div with some sad toon face and a "we didn't find anything' message.

Comment: I prefer sending html throigh the *.php, bcause, Im using JQMobile and Its a mess to intgrate new parts with ajax, you must trigger some events...

Answer (score -1):

```
// set session
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_session'] = array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2'); // your result list
session_write_close();

// get Session
echo ($_SESSION['my_sesson']['var1']);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($result->success) 
    header("location ./view1.php");
else 
    echo 'failed';
```

This is not good practice to use redirects to route requests. You can do it without additional request from the user.

Like this:

```
if ($result->success) {
    include(dirname(__FILE__) .'/'. 'view1.php');
} else { 
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Thus, all variables from handler.php will be available in view1.php.

Comment: But in the case of forms, this causes two things when the user decides to reload the page: 1) they get prompted by their browser and 2) you need to perform your possibly expensive calculations again. Besides that it may cause undesirable state changes (e.g. items are added to cart twice)

Comment: I can not agree with you. if user reloads the page with the data sent, it sends them again and to be notified about it, it works correctly. if user put something in the basket, and then repeated the action, we must count the items. Well, and about the expensive calculations, the lack of calculations on POST request is the potential danger.